# C++ Rectangle to rectangle Collision

Tags: c++, c++11, collision-detection

I'm having a really bad time here looking for the error in my code.

**My collision detection won't work here even the algorithm I searched in Google.**

```
void PollEvents()
{

for (int i = 0;i < NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS; ++i)
{

    Rectangle& a = blocks[i];

    if (mouse.state == GLFW_PRESS)
    {   
        //look for any block to grab
        if (mouse.leftClick && !blocks[selectedBlock].Grab() &&
            a.Hover(mouse.pos.x, mouse.pos.y))
        {
            //prevent grabbing another block
            if (i != selectedBlock) {
                selectedBlock = i;
            }

            a.Grab() = true;

            if (a.IsTypeHorizontal()) {
                diff = mouse.pos.x - a.Left();
            } else {
                diff = mouse.pos.y - a.Top();
            }
        }

        if (a.Grab())
        {   

            for (int j = 0;j < NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS; ++j)
            {
                //skip for any self-checking
                if (i == j) continue;

                Rectangle& b = blocks[j];

                //check for rectangle collision
                if (!a.Collide(b) || b.Collide(a)) {
                    //j++;
                    //how does this block will move.

                    if (a.IsTypeVertical()) {
                        a.SetY(mouse.pos.y - diff);
                    } else {
                        a.SetX(mouse.pos.x - diff);
                    }

                } else {

                    switch (a.sideHit)
                    {
                    case UP:
                        //a.SetY(b.Bottom());
                        printf("UP\n");
                        break;
                    case DOWN:
                        //a.SetY(b.Top() + a.GetHeight());
                        printf("DOWN\n");
                        break;
                    case LEFT:
                        //a.SetX(b.Right());
                        printf("LEFT\n");
                        break;
                    case RIGHT:
                        //a.SetX(b.Left() - a.GetWidth());
                        printf("RIGHT\n");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //check for bound collision
                a.BoundCheck(1.f);
            }

        }

    } else {
        a.Grab() = false;
    }
}
}
```

---

Collision detection:

```
bool Rectangle::Collide(const Rectangle& r) {

if (IsTypeHorizontal()) {
    if (r.Hover(Left(), Top()) && r.Hover(Right(), Top())) {
        sideHit = UP;
        return true;
    } else if (r.Hover(Right(), Bottom()) && r.Hover(Left(), Bottom())) {
        sideHit = DOWN;
        return true;
    }
    // } else if (r.Hover(Left(), Top())) {
        // sideHit = UP;
        // return true;
    // } else if (r.Hover(Right(), Top())) {
        // sideHit = UP;
        // return true;
    // } else if (r.Hover(Right(), Bottom())) {
        // sideHit = DOWN;
        // return true;
    // } else if (r.Hover(Left(), Bottom())) {
        // sideHit = DOWN;
        // return true;
    // }
} else {
    if (r.Hover(Left(), Top()) && r.Hover(Left(), Bottom())) {
        sideHit = LEFT;
        return true;
    } else if (r.Hover(Right(), Top()) && r.Hover(Right(), Bottom())) {
        sideHit = RIGHT;
        return true;
    }
    // } else if (r.Hover(Left(), Top())) {
        // sideHit = LEFT;
        // return true;
    // } else if (r.Hover(Left(), Bottom())) {
        // sideHit = LEFT;
        // return true;
    // } else if (r.Hover(Right(), Top())) {
        // sideHit = RIGHT;
        // return true;
    // } else if (r.Hover(Right(), Bottom())) {
        // sideHit = RIGHT;
        // return true;
    // }
}

return false;

}
```

Code for `Hover`:

```
inline float Hover(float X, float Y) const {
    return  X >= Left() &&
            X <= Right() &&
            Y >= Bottom() &&
            Y <= Top();
}
```

I'm trying to make my own [unblockme](http://www.kiragames.com/games/unblockme-free/).

Please help me on my collision-detection. It's been 3 days now since I got stuck in this problem.

**UPDATE**

I have found out the problem why all rect-rect collision detection won't work in my program.

**Bug:**

```
if (!a.Collide(b)) {

    //Move()

} else {

    //Resolve collision
}
```

This one should be

```
if (!Rectangle::Collide(a, b)) {

    //Move()

} else {

    //Resolve collision

}
```

Making the `Collide()` a `static` member of `Rectangle` because, as you can see in my implementation of `Collide()`, it bases its decision on its own member so `a.Hover(b.x, b.y)` doesn't make any sense.

Hope this helps a little bit to all newbies like me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do rect/rect collision detection, if any of one (edges parallel to x and y axis) rect's four points is inside the other rect, we have a collision.

An easier way than to check each of the four points is to check if one X edge is between both the other rect's X edges, and if one Y edge is between both the other rect's Y edges - if both are true, we have a collision (because the two edges must meet at a point inside of the other rect). So we just check this in both directions:

```
bool isclamped(float mid, float A, float B)
{
    if (A > B)
    {
        return mid >= B && mid <= A;
    }
    return mid >= A && mid <= B;
}

bool checkcollisiononeway(rect rectA, rect rectB)
{
    if (isclamped(rectA.left, rectB.left, rectB.right)
    || isclamped(rectA.right, rectB.left, rectB.right))
    && (isclamped(rectA.bottom, rectB.bottom, rectB.top)
    || isclamped(rectA.top, rectB.bottom, rectB.top))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool checkcollisionbothways(rect rectA, rect rectB)
{
    return checkcollisiononeway(rectA, rectB) || checkcollisiononeway(rectB, rectA);
}
```

To determine the angle of collision after detecting a collision, find the angle between their two centers using `atan2(rectA.y - rectB.y, rectA.x - rectB.x)` (the angle is returned in radians, not in degrees)

Comment: Uhh..this kinda dumbish question but base on the code I posted, w/c one is rectA and rectB ?

Comment: @mr5 One of the rectangles in the collision is rectA, the other one is rectB. They're just placeholder names.

Comment: I mean, is the one that has been `a.Grab()` should be check for the collision?

Comment: @mr5 You need to check in both directions, so it doesn't matter which one is first.

Comment: this one works better than mine. thanks! now I have to deal what to do next after collision.

Comment: Uhhm, another one. Why is that if I removed the rectA, considering `rectA = *this`, it gets me wrong again? maybe this is the reason why all my algorithms won't work.

Comment: @mr5 Make sure you are not mixing up structs/classes, pointers to structs/classes and references to structs/classes. C/C++ is ruthless - if you don't tell it exactly what you want, it'll happily do the wrong thing with often no warning. If you have visual studio or another IDE, try using the debugger. If you do not, try using print statements that print out the values of every value/calculation in the method, to verify that it's using the numbers you think it is. Also, remember that my algorithm is pseudocode, it's not tailored for your code in mind, so you may have to rewrite it substantially